# adding search result into a table without replacing previous result angularjs

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

i have a search text box to search product records from database via api. I am giving **product name** as a search text and displaying the result into a table. But,problem is after a new search only new search records are showing into that table.

I want to insert new search result after the previous result.

Here is my search form[image]

it will display the result the table like below. I have added 'Add to list' to clear search text box and enter new input.
[image]

I want to add new search records after this record(**yellow area**) not to replace it. I am using angularjs with web api. here is my search logic

**angular controller**

```
$scope.search = function () {
    var price = '{materialName: "' + $scope.Prefix + '" }';
    var post = $http({
        method: "POST",
        url: "/api/Price/GetMaterial",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: price,
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }
    });
    post.success(function (data, status) {
        $scope.Customers = data;
        $scope.IsVisible = true;
    });
    post.error(function (data, status) {
        $window.alert(data.Message);
    });
};
```

calling this in ng-repeat and displaying it. How to implement new search record and add to table

Answer (score 1):

On post success instead of doing "$scope.Customers = data", which is replacing all the values of $scope.Customers by the values that returned from server, just append the values in "data" at the end of $scope.Customers. You may use the following code.

```
$scope.Customers = $scope.Customers.concat(data);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.if possible can you re-write the my search code with the edits. I have tried but it is not populating any result.